# emacs drill down shortcut

Tags: c++, emacs

I am new to `emacs`. In Netbeans, you can right click on any object and it will send you directly to the header or implementation file. Is there a shortcut key to do this in `emacs`?

Comment: What do you mean by `object`? You might want to add a language related tag.

Comment: @pmr: Generic term really.. I am using C++.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to create a **TAGS** file first.

If you're on linux:

```
$ ctags -e -R *.h *.cpp
// this will create tags for all .h and .cpp files, 
// starting from the current directory, and recursing into subdirectories.
// -e : emacs tags (as oposed to vi tags, the default)
// -R : recursive
```

You can also add to an existing tags file by using the `--append` flag. For example:

```
$ ctags --append -e -R *.h *.cpp /home/user/jdoe/thirdparty
// This will add to the TAGS file in the current directory
```

When you want to jump to a symbol definition, in emacs use `M-x find-tag`, or `M-.`. It'll ask you where the TAGS file is, and you're set. To pop out, use `M-x pop-tag-mark`, by default mapped to `M-*`.

Note: ctags is alright, but since it's not a compiler, sometimes it'll take you to the wrong place.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `etags` to provide a similar functionality. Once your TAGS file is created, you can use the <kbd>M-.</kbd> shortcut that invokes `(find-tag)`.

Answer (score 1):

As with everything: Emacs gives you several ways to do something, in this case a bunch of them don't work out of the box. You can either use `etags` or if you need a really big hammer [semantic](http://cedet.sourceforge.net/semantic.shtml), which is part of the cedet project. This will give you much more then simply jumping into a header file, but maybe that is what you need.